# Fundamental group of composition of function

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let Y be a simply connected space, and let f : X → Y and g : Y → Z be continuous functions. What is π1(g ◦ f )? Prove your answer.

I think the fundamental group of the composition would be the trivial group. I am not sure how to prove this!!

Any hints?

Comment: The trivial group? What? $\pi_1(f \circ g)$ is a map between groups, not a group!

Comment: $\pi_1$ is a functor that to a map between spaces assigns a homomorphism between the corresponding fundamental groups.

Comment: If $\pi_1(g\circ f)$ is the induced homomorphism, is an *homomorphism*, not a group and $\pi_1(g\circ f)=\pi_1(g)\pi_1(f)$.

Comment: The standard notation for the map induced from the functor $X \to \pi_1(X)$ is actually $f_\star$. Some from the Grothendieck school still writes it as $\pi_1(f)$. It's not a group, but a map.

Comment: Oh!I think I understood a bit: 
As Y is simply connected space, π1(Y) = (e).
Therefore,
π1(f) : π1(X) → π1(e)
π1(g) : π1(e) → π1(Z)

Is this understanding right?
I still don't understand what the composition means?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\pi_1$ is a functor, we have $\pi_1(g\circ f)=\pi_1(g)\circ \pi_1(f)$. However, $Y$ is simply connected, meaning that $\pi_1(Y)=c_{y_0}$, the constant path at the point $y_0$. Thus $g$ is homotopic to a map that sends $Y$ to a point, say $z_0$, in $Z$. Therefore, the homomorphism $\pi_1(g\circ f):\pi_1(X)\rightarrow \pi_1(Z)$ is the trivial homomorphism sending all the elements of the group $\pi_1(X)$ to the neutral element of $\pi_1(Z)$, say $c_{z_0}$.

EDIT : I used that $\pi_1$ is homotopy invariant, which is your previous question ;)